# Use a value of a variable assigned in another file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a variable in an external file "Variable.js" and assign it a value in a file "Page1.html" and then use that variable with that value in another file "Page2.html"
Let's say I have this file "Variable.js" :

```
var myVar
```

The file "Page1.html" with this script:

```
<script>
myVar="Some text"
</script>
```

And the file "Page2.html" like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="Variable.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="para"></p>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#para").text(""+myVar)
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to access "Page2.html" through an `<a href="Page2.html">` in "Page1.html"
and the value "Some Text" to appear in that `<p id="para">`.Is it posible?

Comment: Use query parameters to pass on the data to the next page? `url.com?var=true`

Answer (score 1):

You should use localStorage for this.

```
<script>
    window.localStorage.setItem('MyVar', 'Some text');
</script>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="Variable.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="para"></p>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#para").text(window.localStorage.getItem('MyVar') || '')
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest, using cookies...

look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

so you could do something like

```
document.cookie = "value=Some Text";
```

to write the cookie and

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

to get your cookie

Comment: It's better to use localStorage because cookies are passing to server with each request and also localStorage has better api when with cookies you will need to parse document.cookie string to receive the cookie you need.